# How to receive for sendall in python socket module

Tags: python, sockets, python-sockets

I am fairly new to using sockets, and this will probably have a simple answer that I am overlooking, but since an hour of agonizing has not yielded results so... what the heck.

How do I receive for `.sendall()` in the python socket module? By this I mean how do I receive data from a socket with out a buffer? is there a simple solution for this like some sort of `conn.recvall()` function or do I have it write out logic to do this? If I do have to write logic for it, then how should I do it? Should I just keep using `.recv()` with some arbitrary buffint or do I have to split the inputs into segments before sending? Which is more efficient, or better? Is there a smarter way to go about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`send` and `sendall` will chop your buffer into pieces for sending over the network.  It's important to remember that TCP is a streaming protocol, not a packet protocol.  If you send 1,024 bytes, it might be received by the other end as 1,024 bytes, or as one of 256 and one of 768, or one of 1,000 and one of 24.  The receiver need to know when the transmission is complete.  Sometimes it's fixed buffer, sometimes you'll send a byte count first, sometimes you use a special termination character, sometimes you wait for a timeout.  The receiver just needs to keep calling `.recv` until he knows its done.

Some of the higher level Python packages (like `twisted` (which I recommend)) can handle that for you.

Comment: I dont know why I didn't think of sending over the buffint to set the buffer for the next recv, the code works perfectly now, thanks